# Would like to know common practice of showing Parameters in CSV files

Tags: csv, architecture, export-to-csv

We have website which takes parameters and generate report. We are exporting data in Excel and CSV format. For excel sheet, We show report parameters (selected parameter) as Report Header. But I would like to know how to show report parameters in CSV file. Will it comma seperated with parameters or each line with parameters. Showing Report parameter along with data might be confusing in csv file. Any design principle of showing parameters part of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options I would consider:

1. Creating a separate csv for just the paramters, the net result would be two csv files. One with the data and one with the inputs used to generate the data.
2. Adding a column to the csv and listing the parameters in the first line.
3. If the parameter list is small you may consider constructing the file name from the parameters.
4. Insert it as part of the file metadata, this is something I've never attempted in practice.